# Invoking command at dc - get gpinheritance - wont work

Tags: powershell, command, invoke

I am writing a script where a part of it needs to connect to domain controller and get all the gpo's currently linked to a specific OU.
the line that does that is:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $S -ScriptBlock  {Get-GPInheritance -target $using:Switch -domain shahar.local -server dc01  }
```

$s= credentials, $switch is a a variable that contains an ou that was picked.
those variables exists and they are good.
the error i get is:

Value does not fall within the expected range.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-GPInheritance], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.GetGPInheritanceCommand
    + PSComputerName        : DC01

can anyone please assist?

Comment: Does a version using hard-coded values work?

Comment: you mean if i change variables to static text? no. still doesnt work, same error

Comment: Then it's likely that something in the parameter set is wrong. Without seeing the actual values it's pretty much a guessing game, and the question is too localized. Maybe extra spaces? [Complex](https://serverfault.com/q/880248/85798) domain structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this as answer, because IMO there are too many questions that remain 'unanswered' while the solution is given in a comment.

The error message triggered me to check if any of the variables you use perhaps is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#switch) and in this case it is the variable `$switch`.

Using a different self-defined variable name here like `$selectedOU` should solve the problem.